# how to load deactive category in magento

Tags: magento, categories

How to load category which are not active in magento admin by using below code or something like this

```
$currentCat= Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getId());
```

Comment: did you try normal way ( I mean load the passive category )? What is result?

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories = $this->getStoreCategories();
```

getStoreCategories will return active and passive categories, then you can check the status by

```
$category->getIsActive()
```